# PowerShell CSV manipulation

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a .csv file that contains usernames in the first column.  They are in the form of FirstName LastName.  I want to take the FirstName and add the first character of the LastName onto it, and delete the space.  I then want to add @someemailaddress.com.

Here is the example:

This is what I have:

```
DisplayName, OtherColumn
Sam Jones, otherdata
Paul Jones, otherdata
```

This is what I want:

```
DisplayName, OtherColumn
SamJ@someemailaddrses.com, otherdata
PaulJ@someemailaddress.com, otherdata
```

Ideas?

Comment: @alroc I don't know how to manipulate just the data in column 1.  But, if that could be assigned to a variable, then I am sure that some foreach could be run and look for the first space, and then grab 1 character after the space and then append the email address.

Comment: It can indeed be assigned to a variable and manipulated. Importing CSV data, manipulating it, and exporting it is a very common task in PowerShell. Start by looking at `Import-CSV`, `Export-CSV` and loops. When you come to here looking for help, it's usually expected that you've already attempted a solution and have gotten stuck on some piece of code. Show that you've made an honest effort, and then people can help you get past the obstacle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using [`Import-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx), [`Select-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx), and [`Export-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx), you can set up a pipeline that gets the contents of the CSV file, selects a new calculated `DisplayName` property with an expression that performs your string manipulations, and exports the data back out as CSV.

```
Import-Csv data.csv | Select-Object @{
    Name = "DisplayName"
    Expression = {
        $parts = $_.DisplayName.Split();
        $parts[0] + $parts[1][0] +"@someemailaddress.com"
    }
}, OtherColumn | Export-Csv data-new.csv
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know you could give a dictionary to Select-Object. I've been doing it the hard way all this time...

Comment: @benknighthorse I changed the expression so that it only has to call `Split` once.