# Editing csv files in batch

Tags: csv

i need to edit this csv file in batch

```
id;category;name/code;description;sku;price;weight;options;enable discounts;discounts;availability type;available;pending;images
iqhk8mjh;Software;Quick Heal Antivirus Pro;Quick Heal Antivirus Pro;quickh1;29,90;0;;0;;Dynamic;10;0;C:\Users\Matteo\Dropbox\siti\quick\av2021.png
```

- Delete column 2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,13,14
- change column title from availability to quantity
- delete row with quantity=0
- add column with title codice with static value for example 1234
- then convert in txt (with /t separator)
  Is it possible?

i tryed with powershell

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [how to format questions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You are recommended to at least post what you have tried.  SO is not a code writing service. It's a community to help you improve your skills.

Comment: As per your question: this task is fairly trivial with [AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows) - but of course a multitude of tools can do simple jobs on CSV data.  There are several questions answered here about [manipulating CSV in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145225/powershell-csv-manipulation), if this what you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with PowerShell but I would recommend [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (available [here](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases) for several OSs) instead:

```bash
mlr --icsv --ifs ';' --otsv cut -f 'id,price,available' then rename 'available,quantity' then filter '$quantity != 0' then put '$codice = 1234' file.csv
```

Output:

```
id  price   quantity    codice
iqhk8mjh    29,90   10  1234
```

###### Explanations

- `--icsv --ifs ';'` => set the input format to CSV with `;` as field separator.
- `--otsv` => set the output format to TSV (TAB separated values).
- `cut -f 'id,price,available'` => only keep those fields.
- `rename 'available,quantity'` => rename the field `available` to `quantity`
- `filter '$quantity != 0'` => only keep rows for which `quantity` isn't `0`
- `put '$codice = 1234'` => add the field `codice` with the value `1234` to each row

**note:** `then` is for chaining operations in Miller